# Is a static member of a template globally unique?

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

Looking at the answers available right now, I'm still not sure what the answer is. Here's my example

```
// foo.h
template <class T> class foo
{
public:
    static T t;
};
template <class T> T foo<T>::t = 0;

// a.cpp
#include "foo.h"
foo<int> fa;

// b.cpp
#include "foo.h"
foo<int> fb;

// c.cpp
#include "foo.h"
foo<int> fc;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fc.t = 5;
}
```

Does that mean fa.t and fb.t are also 5? Please let me know if the syntax isn't correct.

Comment: ``cout << fa.t << ' ' << fb.t << endl;``

Comment: @gongzhitaao: What if the compiler has bug and prints something which is not conformant to the Standard?

Comment: `foo<int>` is the name of a class. Just like any other class, its static members are shared by all objects of that type.

Comment: @Nawaz Are you aware of any popular compiler that will produce funny result for this problem?

Comment: @gongzhitaao: How would I know? What is funny result? How would I know if it is funny or not?

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry, what I mean is that basically you would have to count on compilers for these basic language features :)

Comment: @gongzhitaao: Sometimes compilers get things wrong. Compiler authors are human, after all.

Comment: @Nawaz: that said, they are *on average* more accurate implementing the standard than I am reading it. OK, the implementer might have got it wrong, but there's a larger problem which is that the answer might not be dictated by the standard (it could be implementation-defined, unspecified or undefined). That's the reason (more than than the fear of compiler bugs) I would advise learning to read the standard over just trying it out on whatever implementation is handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean fa.t and fb.t are also 5?

Yes, a `static` data member is shared by all instances of a class, and since `fa`, `fb`, and `fc` are all instances of the same class `foo<int>`, they share the `static` data member.

The fact that the type of your objects is an instance of a template is not relevant for this matter, nor is it the fact that your objects are instantiated in different translation units. As Paragraph 9.4/5 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> **Static data members of a class in namespace scope have external linkage** (3.5). A local class shall not have
>   static data members.

In other words, this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    fc.t = 5;
    std::cout << fa.t;
}
```

Will print `5` to the standard output. Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SRz1U$64).

Comment: The live example has only one translation unit. The question has three translation units. So the live example illustrates nothing (in my opinion).

Comment: @Nawaz example really useles, but he is right, static members has external linkage.

Comment: @Nawaz: LWS doesn't let me define more translation units. The example was meant to show that even though accessing the `static` data member with the `.` notation, what you're accessing is an object shared by all instances of that class.

Comment: So what about typedefs? Is this true if i add typedef foo<int> fooint; to d.cpp. Will that class share the static?

Comment: @cppguy: Yes, `typedef` just defines a type alias, so `fooint d;` would be the same as `foo<int> d;`, and would share the same `static` data members as all other instances of `foo<int>`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `fa.t`, `fb.t`, `fc.t` and `foo<int>::t` are
all the same variable.  But I'm not sure if this is what you are
really asking:  `foo<int>::t` and `foo<double>::t` are
*different* variables.

As Pete Becker said in a comment, each instantiation of a class
template results in a class, which behaves exactly as
a non-template class.  On the other hand, each distinct
instantiation is a distinct, *unrelated* class, with its own
static members.